# Using Async for a function that requires wait time

Tags: f#

This is the part of the function that causes me trouble.  I have isolated this part from my main function after some debugging:

```
let testfunction view =
    printfn "Entry point: %s" view
    let df =  ETS.getTimeSeries myrun.tsds (myrun.initiate2 "0019.HK" view defaultbegintime defaultendtime) "unusedlegacystring"
    printfn "I am here"
    df |> ETS.printRecords
let async1 = async{testfunction("BID")}
let async2 = async{testfunction("ASK")}
let gglist = [async1;async2] //Async<unit> list
```

ETS.getTimeSeries returns a Deedle frame from the internet which is saved to df.
ETS.printRecords is a helper function that prints the Deedle frame nicely.

The parameters are all correct.  I know it from running:

```
Async.Start async1
// prints out the dataframe as expected.  Same goes for async2 as well.
```

If I run:

```
gglist
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.Ignore
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The output is only

```
Entry point: BID
Entry point: ASK
```

I suspect this may have something to do with the fact that ETS.getTimeSeries takes anywhere from 3 seconds to 1 minute to pull the data to a Deedle frame and that I am missing some sort of command to wait for getTimeSeries is finished.

As always, any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Update: this may have something to do with the Eikon API itself not being "thread-safe"(???) (ETS.getTimeSeries).  Someone had a solution in C#, and I am trying very hard to re-write it to F#.  I will come back with a solution if possible, thanks

https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/11837/eikon-net-api-accepts-2-3-time-series-requests-and.html

For anyone that is interested, here is the F# implementation of the API (which I copied from the web and claims no credit for):

```
let getTimeSeries (tsds:ITimeSeriesDataService) (setRequestParameters:SetDataRequestParameters) (ric:ReutersInstrumentCode) : seq<IData>  =
    let mutable records = Seq.empty<IData>   // IData is seq<KeyValuePair>
    let mutable transformer = Seq.empty<IData>
    let frame = DispatcherFrame() 
    let dataReceivedCallback (dataChunk:DataChunk) =
        //transformer <- DataChunk.Records.ToTickRecords()
        records <- Seq.append records dataChunk.Records
        frame.Continue <- dataChunk.IsLast |> not  
        () 
    (tsds.SetupDataRequest(ric)
        |> setRequestParameters)  // apply the function to the TimeSeriesDataRequestSetup object
        //.WithFields([]).From(Nullable<DateTime> DateTime.Now).WithAdjustedPrice(true).WithNumberOfPoints(10).WithView("BID")
        .OnDataReceived(Action<DataChunk> dataReceivedCallback)  
        .CreateAndSend() 
        |> ignore
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame)  // "Enters an execute loop"         
    records
```

Credit: https://gist.github.com/roguetrainer/59e4f4664528c40239f1564ef7d6dcee

Update2: Here is a really stupid (but also effective? solution)
Create 3 instances of ETS.getTimeSeries.  Let's call them ETS.getTimeSeries1, ETS.getTimeSeries2 and ETS.getTimeSeries3

Manually hard code task1 with getTimeSeries1 and so on

```
[task1; task2; task3] |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore |> Async.StartImmediate
//work as expected
```

I have a 16core/32thread Gen1 TR CPU, so I guess I can hard code up to 32 threads to fully take advantage of this....

Comment: As far as I can see the async computation expression doesn't really block at any time. Both asyncs should be fully executed, I just assume that there might be something off with the `ETS.printRecords`. As the snippet contains a `Async.ignore` all I assume that it does not return `unit`, right?

Comment: @WalternativE ETS.printRecords is a seq<IData> -> unit function according to Visual Studio. May I ask why it matters and is it correct that Async.ignore is unnecessary?  Thanks =)

Comment: as far as I can tell from the given code the async CE already has the type `Async<unit>` - that's why I asked about the `Async.ignore` function call. I assumed that the `ETS.printRecords`returned a value because you saw the result in the one case and not in the other. As I see from your update you already found the culprit :)